# Nonuniform "lightning" of manually created texture in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10

I'm trying to create a texture manually from my own data and display it. As I could seize in different DirectX docs the main part of code would be written in this manner

```
// Global variables
HWND g_hWnd = NULL;
D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE g_driverType = D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
ID3D10Device *g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
IDXGISwapChain *g_pSwapChain = NULL;
ID3D10RenderTargetView *g_pRenderTargetView = NULL;
ID3D10ShaderResourceView *g_pShaderResource = NULL;
ID3DX10Sprite *g_pSprite = NULL;
ID3D10Texture2D *g_pTexture = NULL;

// Any additional code for creation the window object
// ............

// Initialize DirectX
HRESULT InitDirectX()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(g_hWnd, &rc);
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] = 
    {
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = sizeof(driverTypes)/sizeof(driverTypes[0]);

    // Initialization of the Swap Chain and the Device
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = 64;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = 64;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;
    sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    for (UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++)
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, g_driverType, NULL, D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &g_pSwapChain, &g_pd3dDevice);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            break;
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    ID3D10Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView);
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    g_pd3dDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pRenderTargetView, NULL);

    // Create the Viewport
    D3D10_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = 64;
    vp.Height = 64;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
    g_pd3dDevice->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);


    // Fill the structure of future texture
    D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.Width = 64;
    desc.Height = 64;
    desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, NULL, &g_pTexture );

    // Get the access to the texture data
    D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D mappedTex;
    g_pTexture->Map( D3D10CalcSubresource(0, 0, 1), D3D10_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedTex );

    int cnt = 0;
    UCHAR* pTexels = (UCHAR*)mappedTex.pData;
    ZeroMemory(pTexels, sizeof(pTexels));
    for( UINT row = 0; row < desc.Height; row++ )
    {
        UINT rowStart = row * mappedTex.RowPitch;
        for( UINT col = 0; col < desc.Width; col++ )
        {
            UINT colStart = col * 4;
            if (cnt == 0)
            {
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 255; // Red
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 128; // Green
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 64; // Blue
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255; // Alpha
            } 
            else
            {
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 64;// Red
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 128;// Green
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 255;// Blue
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255;// Alpha
            }
            cnt++;
            cnt %= 2;
        }
    }

    g_pTexture->Unmap( D3D10CalcSubresource(0, 0, 1));

    // Bind shader and texture
    D3D10_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;

    // Fill the shader attributes
    srvDesc.Format = desc.Format;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = desc.MipLevels;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = desc.MipLevels - 1;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(g_pTexture, &srvDesc, &g_pShaderResource);

    // Create sprite object
    hr = D3DX10CreateSprite(g_pd3dDevice, 1, &g_pSprite);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    return S_OK;
}

// Now render the texture

void RenderScene()
{

    float ClearColor[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    g_pd3dDevice->ClearRenderTargetView(g_pRenderTargetView, ClearColor);

    D3DXMATRIX mWorld;
    D3DXMATRIX mView;
    D3DXMATRIX mProjection;

    // Now render the generated texture thus it will be entirelly displayed in window
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&mWorld, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&mProjection, 0.3258f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.01f);

    g_pSprite->SetProjectionTransform(&mProjection);

    D3DXVECTOR3 vEyePt(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 vLookAtPt(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 vUpVec(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&mView, &vEyePt, &vLookAtPt, &vUpVec);

    g_pSprite->SetViewTransform(&mView);

    HRESULT hr;

    g_pSprite->Begin(D3DX10_SPRITE_SORT_TEXTURE);

    // Render sprite based on shader created on the basis of generated texture
    D3DX10_SPRITE SpriteToDraw; // Sprite array
    SpriteToDraw.matWorld = mWorld;
    SpriteToDraw.TexCoord.x = 0.0f;
    SpriteToDraw.TexCoord.y = 0.0f;
    SpriteToDraw.TexSize.x = 1.0f;
    SpriteToDraw.TexSize.y = 1.0f;
    SpriteToDraw.ColorModulate = D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    SpriteToDraw.pTexture = g_pShaderResource;
    SpriteToDraw.TextureIndex = 0;

    hr = g_pSprite->DrawSpritesBuffered(&SpriteToDraw, 1);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Sprite display error", L"Error", 0);
    }

    g_pSprite->Flush();
    g_pSprite->End();

    g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Suddenly, the final result represents the image with nonuniform "lightened" stripes.

[link to image http://savepic.org/7623429.jpg](http://savepic.org/7623429.jpg):

I've tried to change viewpoint parameters, that led to change the number of visible stripes and their shade, but I can't understand the cause of appearance of different blue/orange shades (in code their colors are uniform). Also, if I generate texture that is evenly filled with one color, i.e:

```
for( UINT row = 0; row < desc.Height; row++ )
{
    UINT rowStart = row * mappedTex.RowPitch;
    for( UINT col = 0; col < desc.Width; col++ )
    {
        UINT colStart = col * 4;
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = xxx; // Exact color has no reason
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = yyy; 
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = zzz; 
        pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = ttt; 
    }
}
```

there is no effect of nonuniform shade of the final displayed texture.

Comment: Is this related to "Fog" because the corners of the surface are further from the viewpoint than the center?  Or is it related to a point light source that is fading with distance?  Shot in the dark here, my D3D is rusty to say the least...